How to call the EXACT formula from VBA
I am trying to call Application.WorksheetFunction.Exact. I did do a search trying to find the solution to (so far) no avail.
Here is what I have attempted:
Set deltaCell = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("qry_invalid_deltas").Range("z4")
Set outCell = deltaCell.Offset(0, -1)
Set inCell = outCell.Offset(0, -1)
debug.print(CDbl(deltaCell.Value) <> CDbl(outCell.Value) - CDbl(inCell.Value))
Debug.Print (Application.WorksheetFunction.exact(deltaCell, outCell - inCell))

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you for your assistance.

What happens when you do this?  What's the error?

I get Object does not support this property or method

Not every Excel worksheet function is available via WorksheetFunction. It appears that Exact is one such example. Here's the list of functions available via WorksheetFunction https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction#methods

Since Exact isn't supported by WorksheetFunction, use the equal operator to compare strings exactly as the Exact function:
CStr(deltaCell) = CStr(outCell - inCell)

P. S. The method to compare non-integer numbers involves the comparison tolerance:
Abs(deltaCell - (outCell - inCell)) < tolerance


the reason I was looking for the Exact function is because I ran into the problem of CDbl(deltaCell.Value) = CDbl(outCell.Value - CDblinCell.Value) returning FALSE despite the fact that every calculation that i checked showed such values to be TRUE, and I can even see that the values are true in the debugger. I will use your method, but then I am still baffled by the mystery as to why it would return as FALSE.

Exact is for comparing strings, case senstitive.
You are trying to comapre floating point values. So Exact is not what you want.
To compare floating point values, just use =.
However, you will run into the floating point precision issue.  The solution  for you will depend on the details of what you are trying to achieve. (Typically involves allowing for some tolerance)
(For anyone else who finds this and does want to compare strings, use StrComp with vbBinaryCompare to enforce case senstitive comparison)

Use the "Evaluate" method to use the "Exact" function in VBA;
    MsgBox Evaluate("Exact(A1, B1)")

